# converting a date to string for manipulation in python

Tags: python, datetime

I am new to python and i have written a script that converts a string date coming in to a `datetime` format going out. My problem is that cannot convert the `datetime` object back to a string for manipulation. i have a date eg `2011-08-10 14:50:10` all i need to to is add a `T` between the date and time and a `Z` at the end. unfortunately im using python 2.3 as my application will only accept that.

my code is as follows:

```
fromValue= ''
fromValue = document.Get(self._generic3)
fromValue = fromValue[:fromValue.rindex(" ")]
fromValue = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(time.strptime(fromValue,"%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")))
```

Comment: Hi Clayton, welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest you post a "working" example (e.g. replace the call to `document.Get` with its return value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to format the datetime in [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.
For this purpose, use the `isoformat` method.

```
import datetime as dt 
try:
    import email.utils as eu
except ImportError:
    import email.Utils as eu  # for Python 2.3

date_string="Fri, 08 Aug 2011 14:15:10 -0400"
ttuple=eu.parsedate(date_string)
date=dt.datetime(*ttuple[:6])
print(date.isoformat()+'Z')
```

yields

```
2011-08-08T14:15:10Z
```

Here is link to [isoformat](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3/lib/datetime-datetime.html) and [parsedate](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3/lib/module-email.Utils.html) in the Python2.3 docs.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback i really appreciate it @unubtu my string comes in looking like this "Fri, 08 Aug 2011 14:15:10 -0400"
i have chopped of the "-0400" and kept the rest of the string which i have converted to this format "2011-08-08 14:15:21" i need from here that converted into this '2011-08-08T14:50:10Z' which i cannot do i get an error saying integer required when i try to split it

Answer (score 8):

```
toValue = fromValue.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT %H:%M:%SZ")
```

This should work fine. `datetime.strftime` was available on Python 2.3.

You'd certainly be better off upgrading to **at least** Python 2.5 if at all possible. Python 2.3 hasn't even received security patches in years.

Edit: Also, you don't need to initialize or declare variables in Python; the `fromValue= ''` has no effect on your program.

Edit 2: In a comment, you seem to have said you have it in a string already in nearly the right format:

```
"2011-08-08 14:15:21"
```

so just do

```
'T'.join("2011-08-08 14:15:21".split()) + 'Z'
```

If you want to add the letters while it's a string.

Comment: thanks guys for the help you really helped me alot.
@unubtu your answered worked all i had to do was specify the isoformat which i did and worked!!! thanks a mill

Answer (score 3):

```
fromValue.strftime('%Y-%m-%d T %H:%M:%S Z')
```

http://docs.python.org/release/2.3/lib/module-time.html

http://docs.python.org/release/2.3/lib/node208.html